# reading with java, an element that was generated with javascript

Tags: java, javascript

I have a website that implements a JavaScript that generates some messages elements.

I would like to write a Java program that will read from this messages once they will generate. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use [HtmlUnit](http://www.google.com.sa/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=htmlunit&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/&ei=BNK3TqazL8rLsgbbwIQH&usg=AFQjCNHPMijLD6lsJhr_pTp_Ysz3XN3dHA).

> It has fairly good JavaScript support (which is constantly improving)
>   and is able to work even with quite complex AJAX libraries, simulating
>   either Firefox or Internet Explorer depending on the configuration you
>   want to use.

Comment: This looks promising, I'm looking into it.

Comment: I've downloaded it and tried running the code with some examples that are on the HTMLunit website but all I get when I run my project is Rhino console waiting for input.

Comment: @user811195 I think there are some listeners in HtmlUnit that listens for any popped up messages. Take a look into HtmlUnit or try google.